# How to give hover effect on svg in next?

Tags: next.js

I am using this right now with tailwindcss but it's not working
Please suggest me any way to give hover effect on svg

`<Image className="hover:fill-black" src={IconCopy} alt="Copy_icon" /></div>`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply hover effect for SVGs when you are using it in `img` tag.

Try creating a separate component and apply the class there,

for example,

```jsx
const CopyIcon = ({ className }) => {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      className={className}
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke="currentColor"
    >
      <path
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
        strokeWidth={2}
        d="M9 5H7a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2h10a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2h-2M9 5a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2M9 5a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default CopyIcon;
```

and use it as

```jsx
<CopyIcon className="w-5 h-5 hover:fill-black">
```

**Note:** To get the SVG's code, you can simply open it in your text editor. Make sure convert that to `jsx` syntax with replacing the attribute name (Eg. `className` instead of `class`) using some [tools](https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm).

Comment: Thanks bro, you saved my a lot of time